# How to get a Tasklist in Camunda?

Tags: java, camunda

It looks like the Camunda doesn't provide tasklist with a Java method, and I still cannot find how to redo or skip a task in a case. It puzzles me that why not provide the basic method in Camunda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you currently call tasks?

Camunda has something better than a basic Java method, a [TaskQuery](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.6/org/camunda/bpm/engine/task/TaskQuery.html).
So you can easy find all active tasks

```
List<Task> list = taskService.createTaskQuery()
.active()
.list();
```

or all active task for a user

```
List<Task> list = taskService.createTaskQuery()
.active()
.taskCandidateUser("YOUR_USER")
.list();
```